# Access Guest account System Registry hive from a service application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I need to modify settings of a user-mode program from a local service application using C++ and WinAPIs. With most user accounts, I can access them by reading the following registry keys:

> HKEY_USERS\ [UserSID] \Software

But I can't seem to find a user hive for a built-in Guest account. Any idea where it's settings are stored in the Registry?

PS. The local service is a 32-bit application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Guest account is SID `S-1-5-21-domain-501`, which does not have its own Registry key, AFAIK.

See [Well-Known SIDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379649.aspx) and [Well-known security identifiers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330).

The correct way to manipulate a specific user's Registry hive is to impersonate the user and then use `RegOpenCurrentUser()` to access that user's `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` key normally, not to manipulate the `HKEY_USERS` key directly.